# I rename partition C and now Windows does't start

Tags: windows, boot, windows-xp, partitioning, ntfs

I have Windows XP installed in a SSD with the name: `d:`

I changed the name to `c:` but now Windows XP doesn't start. It only shows the Windows XP logo:

[image: Microsoft Windows XP logo]

Now I started Puppy Linux with a bootable flash drive so I can use GParted to rename the partition to `d:` but I am afraid to broke the partition. I didn't find the way to rename it.

How can I rename the partition?

The partition is NTFS.

Comment: You *may* have some luck by using Linux to modify your Windows registry and replace all occurrences of "D:" to "C:". This should tell Windows to look on C: instead of D: for OS components. I'm fairly certain there is no way to modify the letter Windows assigns a drive without being booted into Windows.

Comment: How were you able to change the drive letter of the system disk while Windows was running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the drive letter of the windows partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/556951/how-can-i-change-the-drive-letter-of-the-windows-partition)

Answer (score 1):

If possible you may try using a USB boot of Windows for recovery. From there, it should allow you to go into the command prompt and utilize DISKPART to assign the proper drive letter to your partition.

You'll want to go into your boot menu to boot from the USB. So be ready to hit the correct function key for that when your computer begins to load up.

Following that, you'll simply select the language of your preference. Then, select **ADVANCED OPTIONS**! You ***DO NOT*** want to select "Recover from a drive".

Once Advanced Options is selected it should show an option to boot with Command Prompt. Select, and once loaded type "diskpart" into the prompt and hit enter. From there It'll give you the options for that command. If you run into trouble, or aren't sure of the syntax for a particular command type "diskpart /?". This will show some helpful tips on using the command.

If you have any other questions let me know, I'd be happy to help! Please keep us informed of the results, too.

Comment: Diskpart only allow me to create or delete partitions.